# sqldatasource select command didn't work

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a problem doing search in asp.net, when I try to run the code in sqlserver or using query buider it works fine. But when I run the program in browser, the gridview didn't even show up. Help plz.

```html
protected void btnsearchadvance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (txtname.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                search = "NmBengkel LIKE '%" + txtname.Text + "%'";
            }
            if (txtaddress.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                search = search + " AND Address LIKE '%" + txtaddress.Text + "%'";
            }
            if (txttelp.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                search = search + " AND NoTelp LIKE '%" + txttelp.Text + "%'";
            }
            if (txtnote.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                search = search + " AND Note LIKE '%" + txtnote.Text + "%'";
            }

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM mst_bengkel where " + search;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can use parameterized Query like
    _cmd = new SqlCommand();
    _cmd.CommandText = "prc_GetSampleData";
    _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     _cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txtname.Text.Trim();
    _cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtaddress.Text.Trim();
    _cmd.Parameters.Add("@telp", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txttelp.Text.Trim();
    _cmd.Parameters.Add("@note", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtnote.Text.Trim();
    _cmd.Connection = _con;
    _con.Open();

    try
    {
    sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    sqlDA.Fill(ds, "SampleData");
    }
     catch (Exception ex) { _ex = ex; }
                finally { if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { _con.Close(); } }





Here is the procedure 

Create procedure prc_GetSampleData
@name varchar(50) =null,
@address varchar(50)=null,
@telp varchar(50)=null,
@note varchar(50)=null
AS 
BEGIN
Declare @prmname varchar(50)='%%'
Declare @prmaddress varchar(50)='%%'
Declare @prmtelp varchar(50)='%%'
Declare @prmnote varchar(50)='%%'




if @name is not null
begin
set @prmname=@name
end

if @address is not null
begin
set @prmaddress=@address
end


if @telp is not null
begin
set @prmtelp=@telp
end

if @note is not null
begin
set @prmnote=@note
end



SELECT * FROM mst_bengkel where name Like  @prmname  and address like @prmaddress and telp like @prmtelp and note like @prmnote 




END
```

Comment: can you give me the complete code where to put the parameterized query ? should I make the procedure on the sqlserver ?

Comment: yes u have to make procedure example:'prc_GetSampleData'

Comment: okay and the parameterized query ? how's the code in visual studio ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use  stored procedure.


 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;



 #region Declaration
    private SqlConnection _con;
    private SqlCommand _cmd;
    private SqlDataAdapter _sda;
    private Exception _ex;
    private SqlDataReader _sdr;
 #endregion



 protected void btnsearchadvance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
_con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionstring"].ToString());
 _cmd = new SqlCommand();
_cmd.CommandText = "prc_GetSampleData";
_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
_cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = txtname.Text.Trim();
_cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtaddress.Text.Trim();
_cmd.Parameters.Add("@telp", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txttelp.Text.Trim();
_cmd.Parameters.Add("@note", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = txtnote.Text.Trim();
_cmd.Connection = _con;
_con.Open();

try
{
_sda = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
_sda.Fill(ds, "SampleData");
}
 catch (Exception ex) { _ex = ex; }
            finally { if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { _con.Close(); } }

 }
```

Comment: what is 'ds' on _sda.Fill refer to ?

Comment: I try to run without the code between try catch final because I still got error on 'ds' not refer to anything, and I got error that show to _con "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I really have no idea when facing that kind of error

Comment: private DataSet _ds;

Comment: _ds = new DataSet(); add this Code in  btnsearchadvance_Click function

Comment: Error says we have not declared ds.

Comment: still have the error after I click button search that shows "Object reference not sen to an instance of an object" refers to sqlconnection